# Check for date less than age 90 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have condition in which I need Date of birth must be less than system date, not null, age less 90 years then insert into table. I don't know how to use age less than 90 in query

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO table2 (dob)

SELECT dob
FROM table1
WHERE dob <= sysdate
AND dob IS NOT NULL;
```

Please tell me how to use less than age 90 in query

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT dob
FROM table1
WHERE
    TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, dob) / 12) < 90 AND
    dob IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT dob
FROM table1
WHERE dob > ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -90*12)
AND dob IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with `interval` constants for this kind of queries:

```
select *
from table1
where dob > trunc(sysdate) - interval '90' year;
```

There is no need to add an additional `dob is not null` condition because `dob > ...` will only return something if `dob` is not null.